# Extra zeroes in python received list when transfered over RF from Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, radio-transmission

I am trying to send a array from the Arduino over NRF24L01 modules to be received by a python Raspberry Pi program. The below script is the loop in my Arduino program.

```cpp
void loop() {

    int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
    MoistureLevel=analogRead(moistureA0);
    int temp = DHT.temperature;
    int humid = DHT.humidity;

    int data[]={MoistureLevel, temp, humid};

    delay(1000)

    radio.write(data, sizeof(data));
}
```

The below code is what has been written for the RPi.

```
while(1):
    #ackPL = [1]
    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1 / 100)
    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage,radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())

    print(receivedMessage)
```

When it prints the message I get the following:

```
[6, 0, 21, 0, 26, 0]
[6, 0, 21, 0, 26, 0]
[7, 0, 21, 0, 26, 0]
[6, 0, 21, 0, 28, 0]
```

It seems to be adding another zero in. Additionally, if the value in the first location increases above 100, it will sometimes fill in the second location with another number as it did for the first and third rows.  For the second row it kept the right number but still had the extra zeros.

```
[17, 1, 21, 0, 23, 0]
[255, 0, 21, 0, 23, 0]
[26, 1, 21, 0, 23, 0]
```

I have gotten a Python script to accept numbers individually.  That is seen below.  If I were to radio.write() each number individually from the Arduino they would all show up on correctly on the Pi.  However, I wanted to send all three numbers together in a list, so that I would have a list for each reading.

```
while(1):
    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1 /100)
    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    print("Received:  {}".format(receivedMessage))

    print("Translating into Unicode char")
    string = ""
    for n in receivedMessage:
        if (n >= 32 and n <= 126):
            string += chr(n)
    print("Message decodes to:  {}".format(string))
```

Is anyone able to offer direction for how to receive a correct list on the Python side?

Comment: The issue might be with the Arduino's data acquisition functions.  How many bits do the data items contain?  If they are 16-bit integers they are represented by 2 bytes, a least significant byte and a most significant byte.  When you transmit these values, they would show up on the Python side as two bytes for each integer on the Arduino side.  At least that would be one possible way for it to work.

Comment: @PaulCornelius is **spot on** on the issue, I advice you to [read the documentation of python struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), with which you would be able to solve your problem in a *general way*. I used exactly that in the past.